# Audio file progress is not displayed in Chrome/Chromium browsers

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, centos7

I have a situation where .mp3 audio files can be played from my site, but in Chrome and Chromium-based browsers (e.g. Edge), the progress bar does not display the location and you are unable to advance forward by clicking in the progress bar. In Firefox and IE it works correctly.

This happens when I embed the file in the page with `<audio>` tags, but also when I access the file directly in the browser. So it's not an application issue.

I've tested the same file on another server and it works in Chrome, so I suspect there is something going on at the server level that is affecting how it's loading, but have not been able to pinpoint the cause. We're running Centos7.

Answer (score 0):

I traced the issue to the Apache mod_pagespeed module. Ironic, as this is a module produced by Google and the issue only affected chromium based browsers. I suspect it has something to do with how that module tries to progressively download content. I decided to just disable the module altogether and the audio files began working as expected.